# php searching multiple fields on msql and return exactly answer

Tags: php, mysql

my be i may change the question explanation since no any help,But I real want help.
I have a search box in my form which enable user to search student data in mysql table, I only succeed on searching single field eg (first name or second name or sir name) the BIG problem to me is how to search multiple field on  the same text input field or any number of text input field eg(text1, text2, text3) only I want is to have exactly result. Sorry if any mistake.

Here the php codes I use to get single field search.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><input type="text" name="query" value=""/>
     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />

     <?php
     $query="query";

//mysql_connect

$query='query';
if (isset($_GET['query'])) 
    {    
        $query=$_GET['query'];

        // Instructions if $_POST['value'] exist    
    } 

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stdreg_exam 
                  WHERE (`fname` LIKE '%".$query."%') or (`secname` LIKE '%".$query."%')or  
                     (`date` LIKE '%".$query."%') or (`surname` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or  
    die(mysql_error());


$raw_results2 = mysql_query("SELECT(idnumber) FROM student 
                           WHERE (`fname` LIKE '%".$query."%') or (`secname` LIKE  
                            '%".$query."%') or (`date` LIKE '%".$query."%')or    
                              (`surname` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());  


// * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
// articles is the name of our table

// '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
// it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
// or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
    // if one or more rows are  
    returned do following


                    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
                        while($results2 = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results2)){

                            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into  
                            array, while it's valid it does the loop

    echo "<table width='750' height='5' cellpadding='2'  
                                         cellspacing='0' border='0'>";
echo"<tr><td>Std_id</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>English</td> 
               <td>Kiswahili</td><td>Geograph</td><td>Ict</td><td>Science</td> 
                <td>History</td><td>Pds</td><td>V skill</td><td>French</td> 
                 <td>Religion</td><td>Civics</td>";
echo "<h4>&nbsp;".$results['exam_name']."&nbsp; Examination result for   
                  &nbsp;" .$results['fname']."&nbsp;" .$results['secname']  
."&nbsp;".$results['surname']."&nbsp;".$results['class']."&nbsp;Class"."&nbsp;        
                      held on</p>".$results['date']."<hr><th>"; echo"<tr>";

echo ""."<td>".$results2['idnumber'].""."<td>".$results['mathematics']."%"." 
               <td>".$results['english']."%"."<td>".$results['kiswahili']."%"."  
               <td>".$results['geograph']."%"."<td>".$results['ict']."%"."
               <td>".$results['science']."%"."<td>".$results['history']."%"." 
               <td>".$results['pds']."%"."<td>".$results['vskill']."%"." 
               <td>".$results['french']."%"."<td>".$results['religion']."%"." 
               <td>".$results['civics']."%"."</td></p>";echo"</table>";                
//posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id  
($results['id'])
}

}
}
               else{ 
                   // if there is no matching rows do following
                   echo "No such information in School database";
               }

}
                     else{ 
                         // if query length is less than minimum
                         echo "Enter more strings!!!Minimum length is ".$min_length; "Charactes";
                     }

?>
```

Comment: duplicate of [how to search mysql by date,name,exam\_name and class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885659/how-to-search-mysql-by-date-name-exam-name-and-class)

Comment: Are the $raw_results and $raw_results2 showing any errors or are they retrieving the required data?

Comment: Yeah! are retrieving required data

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 text fields, let's say text1, text2 and text3 and you need to get search result from DB. You could try something like this

```
$query = "SELECT your_feilds,another_fields FROM your_table WHERE 1=1 ";

if($_POST['text1'])
    $query .= " AND text1_field like '%$_POST['text1']%' ";

if($_POST['text2'])
    $query .= " AND text2_field like '%$_POST['text2']%' ";

if($_POST['text3'])
    $query .= " AND text3_field like '%$_POST['text3']%' ";


$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: ok, but when i you say 1=1 does it means that it limit for only one row?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer from #Shafeeq is very functional and is working as I have used the same approach for one of my applications, but there is one issue, if you have a another field let us say date and you want to search between two dates. 
The query will be like that

```
if($_POST['from_date'] && $_POST['To_date'])
$query .= " AND date between '$from_field' AND '$To_field' ";
```

Then It does not work for other fileds